# mongodb: Cant update a model through a mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having following values in my User model.

```
 "courseId" : [
                "5ac37f5cd494e905b86c2433",
                "5ac3861b8ef3100798036040",
                "5ac42ce009092c3058893590",
                "5ac47e2787f5a70428640ed3",
                "5ac710fbc1c4ea39b8050c94",
                "5ac3861b8ef3100798036040",
                "5ac3861b8ef3100798036040",
                "5acc4b59336cfc3de4b05e69",
                "5acc4b59336cfc3de4b05e69"
        ],
```

As you can see, the last two values are duplicate values. I am trying to update them through this mongoose query:

```
User.update({ "_id": req.params.userid }, { $set: { courseId: User.distinct("courseId", { "_id": req.params.userid }) } }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("distinct done");
                }
            });
```

Here, i can assure you that the function is receiving user id in `req.params` but it is not removing duplicate values. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`distinct`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#distinct_distinct) will execute asynchronously. You need to call the `update` in the callback

```
User.distinct("courseId", { "_id": req.params.userid }, function(err, courseIds){
 //handle err
  User.update({ "_id": req.params.userid }, { $set: { courseId: courseIds } }, 
     function (err) {
       if (err) {
         console.log(err);
       } else {
          console.log("distinct done");
       }
     });
});
```